# Theoretical variance of an unbiased estimator.

Tags: statistics, estimation, variance

Let $n_1, n_2, n_3$ denote sample sizes of $3$ samples of people, where $n_1 < n_2 < n_2$ and let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ denote the number of left handed people in each sample. Let $\hat{p_{1}} = \frac{(X_1)}{n_1},  \hat{p_{2}} = \frac{(X_2)}{n_2}, \hat{p_{3}} = \frac{(X_3)}{n_3}$

Show that $\hat{p_{12}} = \frac{(n_1)(\hat{p_1}) + (n_2)(\hat{p_2})}{n_1 +n_2}$ is an unbiased estimator, and find the variance. In order to show unbiasedness you prove that $E(\hat{p_{12}}) = \mu$, by allowing $\frac{X_1}{n_1}$ etc to = $\mu$ as they follow a normal distribution. In order to find theoretical variance, do i need to prove that  $\frac{\sigma^2}{n} = 0$, or find it in terms of $X_1, n_1$  etc by showing that $\frac{\sigma}{n} = \frac{\sum(X_i - X_{bar})}{n}$.

Comment: I would assume that the probability of an individual being left-handed is $\mu$ and then you find $\text{var}(\hat{p}_{12}) = E\left[ (\hat{p}_{12}-\mu)^2\right]$ in terms of $\mu$.  This is binomially rather than normally distributed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is not specified whether it is normally or binomially distributed. Is there any significant difference in the variance or mean calculation if we assume the sample sizes are large enough?

Comment: You are going to have to use the binomial distribution to find the variances of $X_1$ and $X_2$ so you may as well go on using it

Comment: An unbiased estimator of what? Also, your (X) notation is peculiar and should be defined.